# Importing all classes in java package in jruby

Tags: java, import, jruby

I am looking for the syntax equiv to

```
import com.mycom.mypack.*
```

for jruby

e.g. java_import com.mycom.mypack.

This feature was added via JRUBY 6334 JIRA

https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-6334

But it is not clear to me what is the actual syntax.

Here is the comment by mr Jruby himself :

```
Charles Oliver Nutter added a comment - 17/Feb/12 1:13 PM

commit a39a7440c21b411c4592a27d2ef9e0ca73736590
Author: Charles Oliver Nutter <headius@headius.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 17 13:06:24 2012 -0600

    Fix JRUBY-6334: Import multiple classes via java_import

    I opted to just go with the simple version to resolve this issue.
    I have nothing against introducing some syntax to import multiple
    classes from the same package, but I didn't see anything that we
    all agreed looked nice, and in any case you could use other Ruby
    constructs to build the list of full names you pass to java_import.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'java'

module JavaUtil
  include_package "java.util"
end

JavaUtil::Date.new
```